# Redirect user to Google+ on follow button click

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I want to redirect users to prizepage.html after the google plus follow button is clicked.

How can I do it?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div class="follow">
  <h1>Follow us for your free prize</h1>
</div>

<div class="g-follow" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="24" data-href="https://plus.google.com/101560853443212199687" data-rel="publisher"></div>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Comment: What are you using,  to handle your events? Angular or JS or JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. The [Google+ Follow Button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/) shows the supported features and there is no event or callback triggered when the user click or follows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<button onclick="location.href = 'prizepage.html ';" id="myButton" class="g-follow float-left submit-button" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="24" data-href="https://plus.google.com/101560853443212199687" data-rel="publisher" ></button>
```